# Nest InjectRedis incompatible with typescript 5.1.6

Tags: typescript, redis, nestjs, incompatibility

I have updated my typescript version from 4.9.5 to 5.1.6 in my NestJs project and @InjectRedis no longer works

This is the code:

`@Injectable() export class MyService { constructor( @InjectRedis('REDIS') private readonly redisService: Redis, ) {} ... }`

The error I receive is: "Unable to resolve signature of parameter decorator when called as an expression.
Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | symbol'."

Maybe someone has an idea on how to fix it?

I really have no idea where to start to fix it.

Comment: what's the version of nestjs? run `npx nest info`

Comment: This is the result shown:

swagger version            : 7.1.1
testing version            : 10.0.5
common version             : 10.0.5
config version             : 3.0.0
core version               : 10.0.5
jwt version                : 10.1.0
cli version                : 10.1.8
 version                   : 1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find a clean solution for this. But I have created this issue https://github.com/nest-modules/ioredis/issues/267.

However, a workaround may be **@(InjectRedis as any)('REDIS')** instead of **@InjectRedis('REDIS')**.

Answer (score -1):

That limitation was fixed on `@nestjs/common` v9.3.0

Make sure you have you're using the latest version (or at least the latest of NestJS v9) of all your `@nestjs/*` packages

Comment: I am currently using @nestjs/common v10.0.5

Comment: This is solved by using @(InjectRedis as any) instead of @InjectRedis but I think there must be a cleaner way to solve it